# Why is "Tisch" in "Der Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch" in dative instead of accusative case?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

> Der Apfel liegt auf dem Tisch.

Can someone explain me why *Tisch* is in dative case and not in akkusative?

Answer (score 6):

German has nine **dual-way prepositions**: **an**, **auf**, **hinter**, **in**, **neben**, **über**, **unter**, **vor** and **zwischen**. These prepositions can take either the dative case or the accusative case, depending on whether a place or a direction is meant. Telling the two cases apart can be a bit tricky. Luckily, most times the verb commands direction or place.

> Ich lege den Apfel **auf den** Tisch. ← It's a direction, the verb *legen* requires one.
>
> Der Apfel liegt **auf dem** Tisch. ← It's a place, the verb *liegen* requires one.

Note this is only true for these nine prepositions. Other prepositions as *zu* or *aus* always take the dative case though they mean a direction, or, as *durch*, always take the accusative case though they mean a place. There is also a small number of genitive prepositions.

Also note there is a small number of prepositions as *entlang* which take a different case depending on whether they are used as prepositions or postpositions.