# German case identify

Tags: grammatical-case

How I can identify Akkusativ or Dativ Case  while using Two-way preposition.

Comment: Do you mean: *How do I know if I have to use Akkusativ or Dativ?*

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/why-is-tisch-in-der-apfel-liegt-auf-dem-tisch-in-dative-instead-of-accusativ/49661#49661

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48843/the-difference-between-auf-and-an-when-talking-about-a-specific-location/48845#48845

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38189/dativ-and-akkusativ-problem/38195#38195